# Excel workbook always read only after creation with Open XML

Tags: excel, openxml, openxml-sdk

I've used Open XML 2.0 to dump some data into a spreadsheet from a database.  The requirement is that the users can add extra data into the sheet, however when testing I noticed I couldn't save over the existing workbook.

I checked the info panel and the workbook is set as read-only. I certainly didn't set this is my code. Any ideas?